# RVM doesn't seem to save installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have been using RVM for almost a year now without a problem, but suddenly it started to behave odd a day ago. First of all I wasn't able to enter the Rails console or server - it just told me that it couldn't be found anywhere. After running `bundle install` it fetched all Gems again as if none of them had been installed previously. This worked until I restarted my machine - after that I had to bundle again.

I am not aware of changing anything in the system that could trigger this kind of behaviour. Did anybody experience something like it before?

I am running the latest stable RVM release on Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
rvm list
```

You should see something like this:

```
   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.0-preview1 [ x86_64 ]
```

The `=*` indicates `ruby-2.1.0-preview1` is my current and default ruby version.

Try switching to another ruby version, in my case:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0
```

the `rvm list` command should now yield ( `=>` means current, `*` default):

```
=> ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.1.0-preview1 [ x86_64 ]
```

What's happening with you is probably that rvm is switching versions when you reboot. You might want to set the version you want to use as default, in my case:

`rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0 --default`

```
rvm list

=* ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0-preview1 [ x86_64 ]
```